# The parameter must be defined

Tags: symfony

I store the keys Stripe in the parameters.yml.dist file, I have the following error message : The parameter "public_key" must be defined.

```
public function paiementAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $token = $request->get('stripeToken');

        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($this->getParameter("private_key"));

        \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
            "amount" => 1000,
            "currency" => "eur",
            "source" => $token,
            "description" => "First test charge!"
        ));

        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'Paiement accepté');
    }

    return $this->render('saya25LouvreBundle:Ticket:paiement.html.twig', array(
        'public_key' =>  $this->getParameter("public_key"),
    ));
}
```

Vue :

```html
<form action="{{ path('saya25_louvre_paiement') }}" method="POST">
        <script
                src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                data-key="{{ public_key }}"
                data-amount="1000"
                data-name="paiement"
                data-description="test"
                data-image="http://www.france-hotel-guide.com/fr/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/musee-louvre.jpg"
                data-locale="auto"
                data-zip-code="true">
        </script>
    </form>
```

[image]

Comment: check if the `public_key` is correctly configured in the `parameters.yml.dist` and that you have launch the `composer install` command from the CLI (so the files  `parameters.yml` will be updated)

Comment: Finally, I did not update composer when I touched the file parameters, it works, thanks :)

Comment: Hi @clement if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if the `public_key` is correctly configured in the `parameters.yml.dist` and that you have launch the composer install command from the CLI (so the files `parameters.yml` will be updated):

```
>composer install
```

Hope this help